# cloudformation Template format error: Every Resources object must contain a Type member

Tags: amazon-vpc, aws-cloudformation

Hi I hope someone can help tell me what I am doing wrong. I am writing a CF template that just adds a VPN Gateway to a VPC. No need to update routing tables etc.

I am using the below template but I get an error that I can't quite see the problem, I thought an extra pair of eyes might help!
:
Template validation error: Template format error: Every Resources object must contain a Type member.

Template:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

"Description" : "CF Just add a VPN Gateway to a VPC ",

"Parameters" : {

"targetVPCtoAttachGatewayTo"    : {
        "Description"   : "VPC ID to attach VPN Gateway",
        "Default"       : "vpc-xxxxx",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id" 
    }
},

"Resources" : {

"VPNGateway" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPNGateway",
    "Properties" : {
    "Type" : "ipsec.1",
    "Tags" : [
        {"Key": "Name", "Value": {"Fn::Join": ["",["Virtual Private Gateway for ", { "Ref": "targetVPCtoAttachGatewayTo"} ] ]}}]
    }
},

"AttachVpnGateway" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
    "DependsOn" : "VPNGateway",
    "Properties" : {
    "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "targetVPCtoAttachGatewayTo" },
    "VpnGatewayId" : { "Ref" : "VPNGateway" }
    }
},

"Outputs" : {
}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue, curly brackets in the wrong place. Working template below.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

"Description" : "CF Just add a VPN Gateway to a VPC ",

"Parameters" : {

"targetVPCtoAttachGatewayTo"    : {
        "Description"   : "VPC ID to attach VPN Gateway",
        "Default"       : "vpc-xxxxx",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id" 
    }
},

"Resources" : {

"VPNGateway" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPNGateway",
    "Properties" : {
    "Type" : "ipsec.1",
    "Tags" : [
        {"Key": "Name", "Value": {"Fn::Join": ["",["Virtual Private Gateway for ", { "Ref": "targetVPCtoAttachGatewayTo"} ] ]}}]
    }
},

"AttachVpnGateway" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
    "DependsOn" : "VPNGateway",
    "Properties" : {
    "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "targetVPCtoAttachGatewayTo" },
    "VpnGatewayId" : { "Ref" : "VPNGateway" }
    }
    }
},

"Outputs" : {
}}
```